# How to concat an int to a wchar_t* in C++?

Tags: c++, int, wchar-t, wchar

I have to create and write on N files, everyone must have an integer ending to identificate it.

This is my piece of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    uscita.open("nameFile"+i+".txt", ios::out); 
    uscita <<  getData() << endl;
    uscita.close();     
}
```

And that's what I would like to find in my directory after execution:

```
nameFile0.txt
nameFile1.txt
nameFile2.txt
...
nameFileMAX.txt
```

The problem of the above code is that I get the compilin' error:

> error C2110: '+' Impossible to add two pointers

If I try to create a string for the name, another problem comes in:

```
string s ="nameFile"+i+".txt";
uscita.open(s, ios::out);
```

And the problem is:

> error C2664: you cannot convert from string to `const wchar_t*`

What can I do?  How can I create files with different names concating `int` to `wchar_t*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `wstringstream`

```
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << "nameFile" << i << ".txt";
uscita.open(wss.str().c_str(), ios::out);
```

Comment: A `wstringstream` would be required here, actually.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. The compiler says: error C2664, impossible to convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const wchar_t *'

Comment: You need to use `.c_str()`, updating answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::to_wstring`:

```
#include <string>

// ...

std::wstring s = std::wstring("file_") + std::to_wstring(i) + std::wstring(".dat");
```

(Then use `s.c_str()` if you need a C-style `wchar_t*`.)

Answer (score 0):

That is easier and faster:

```
wchar_t fn[16];
wsprintf(fn, L"nameFile%d.txt", i);
uscita.open(fn, ios::out);
```

Comment: Just a warning. `sprintf`, `wsprintf` and friends often lead to buffer overflows if you're not _really_ careful. (Either now or when the code is being maintained later.)