# How to concat integer with wchar_t

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to concat an integer with wchar_t, tried below method but its crashing

```
const wchar_t mySalvo[10] = L"Group:";  // THis is global
int salvo = 0;  
wchar_t buffer[1] = L"\n";
itoa(salvo, buffer, 1);
wcscat(mySalvo, buffer);  // app crashes here
```

ITs in C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concat an int to a wchar\_t\* in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609842/how-to-concat-an-int-to-a-wchar-t-in-c)

Comment: Why do you tag "c++" then? :P

Comment: I am working on vc++ with c file

Comment: @sijith I'm a bit confused. You are using VC++ and you are trying to compile a "C file" in C++ mode? (Since AFAIK VC++ does not support real "C")

Comment: Actually my project is c++ but one file alone in c and in that c file I need to apped integer to wchar_t

Comment: `wchar_t buffer[1] = L"\n";` You do not have sufficient memory to hold a string. You need to provide a place for terminating 0.

Comment: I incresed size to 5 but still crashing on wcscat(mySalvo, buffer);

Comment: @L.F. yes VS does support real C, but some parts like VLAs (and maybe others) are missing.

Comment: The C specific solution seems to be [swprintf() or better snwprintf_s()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you! I did not know that :)

Comment: you've made `mySalvo` a const, so that is telling the compiler you won't ever change the contents of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues with this code:

```
const wchar_t mySalvo[10] = L"Group:";  // THis is global
int salvo = 0;  
wchar_t buffer[1] = L"\n";
itoa(salvo, buffer, 1);
wcscat(mySalvo, buffer);  // app crashes here
```

- First of all, using a global is not best practice. There doesn't appear to be any good reason for it to be global, so just make it local to where you need it.
- Second, you've specified it is a constant string, and initialised it to a string literal, which means it will probably be stored in a read-only segment of memory. Yet you're writing into it with `wcscat` (your compiler surely gave you a warning??).
- Also the string is limited to 10 `wchar_t` elements, so even if it weren't read-only, it would only be long enough to store a 3 digit number.
- the buffer intended to store your converted string is one wide character long (and the initialisation to newline is pointless) so you will overflow your buffer with any value of salvo above 9.
- the third parameter to `itoa` is the number base, which would normally be 10. It is meaningless to have a number of base 1.
- you're using `wcscat` to write into a constant string, which is verboten, even assuming it were long enough.

So there's a lot of fundamentals here you need to come to terms with. String allocation, memory initialisation, arrays, constant variables and constant literals, and more.

What you are trying to do is simply produce a formatted string. The [`sprintf` family of string formatting functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) provide all you could possibly need, plus a secure way of doing it.

The simplest solution would be something like this:

```
void show_message(unsigned salvo)
{
    wchar_t message[64];
    swprintf_s(message, sizeof(message), L"Group: %u\n", salvo);

    // do something with message!
}
```

So if you called `show_message(123)`, the resulting value in `message` would be: `"Group: 123\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

mySalvo is const - which was spotted by Chris.

And on top of it

```
wchar_t buffer[1] = L"\n";
itoa(salvo, buffer, 1); -
wcscat(mySalvo, buffer);  // app crashes here
```

it is undefined behavior asd you do not have enough space to accommodate `L"\n"`. Both calls invoke the UB. `itoa` will not work with the wchar_t strings. You need to find the appropriate function.

try `wchar_t buffer[2] = L"\n";` instead

Comment: Thsi worked but crashed on wcscat(mySalvo, buffer); even after increasing buffer size

Comment: See the rest of UBs in your code (BTW I think you hold the world record  of UBs/line)

Comment: Remove `const` as well :)

Comment: mySalvo is already declared an assigned gloabally so wcscat crashes as its size is exceding while copying

Comment: `const wchar_t mySalvo[10] = L"Group:";  // THis is global` => `wchar_t mySalvo[16] = L"Group:";  // THis is global`

Comment: THanks P__J__
I done some thing like this  int size = wcslen(mySalvo);
 mySalvo[size-1] = (salvo + 1) + '0';  My salvo count is below 10